# Java Eclipse - Output when running from command prompt is not the same as through IDE

Tags: java, eclipse

this was asked on superuser https://superuser.com/questions/1364594/java-eclipse-output-when-running-from-command-prompt-is-not-the-same-as-throug but I was told to ask here instead.

I am very new to Java and the eclipse IDE and have an issue when running my Java code from the command prompt on Windows. If I run the code through the eclipse IDE this is the output I get

```
Message number 0
Message number 1
Message number 2
Timeout. Client is closing.
```

However, if I run the code through the command prompt `java test.Main`, I get a lot of empty lines between the messages on the command prompt.

```
//Hundreds of empty lines 
Message number 0
//Hundreds of empty lines
Message number 1
//Hundreds of empty lines
Message number 2
//Hundreds of empty lines
Timeout. Client is closing.
```

I have tried adding simple checks to not print any output if the string is either NULL or empty but it has not worked. Below is my code. I have spent quite a lot of time on this but have no idea what is causing it.

> Main.java

```
package test;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

// create 5 processes

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int port = 50001;
        UdpUnicastServer server = new UdpUnicastServer(port);
        UdpUnicastClient client = new UdpUnicastClient(port);

        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        executorService.submit(client);
        executorService.submit(server);
    }
}
```

> UdpUnicastClient.java

```
package test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.SocketException;

/**
 * Created by dan.geabunea on 6/3/2016.
 */
public class UdpUnicastClient implements Runnable {
    private final int port;

    public UdpUnicastClient(int port) {
        this.port = port;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        /**
         * Bind the client socket to the port on which you expect to
         * read incoming messages
         */
        try (DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket(port)) {
            /**
             * Create a byte array buffer to store incoming data. If the message length
             * exceeds the length of your buffer, then the message will be truncated. To avoid this,
             * you can simply instantiate the buffer with the maximum UDP packet size, which
             * is 65506
             */

            byte[] buffer = new byte[65507];

            // Set a timeout of 3000 ms for the client.
            clientSocket.setSoTimeout(3000);
            while (true) {
                DatagramPacket datagramPacket = new DatagramPacket(buffer, 0, buffer.length);

                /**
                 * The receive method will wait for 3000 ms for data.
                 * After that, the client will throw a timeout exception.
                 */
                clientSocket.receive(datagramPacket);

                String receivedMessage = new String(datagramPacket.getData());
                if(receivedMessage != null && !receivedMessage.isEmpty()) {
                    System.out.println(receivedMessage);
                }
            }
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Timeout. Client is closing.");
        }
    }
}
```

> UdpUnicastServer.java

```
package test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.*;

/**
 * Created by dan.geabunea on 6/3/2016.
 */
public class UdpUnicastServer implements Runnable {
    /**
     * The port where the client is listening.
     */
    private final int clientPort;

    public UdpUnicastServer(int clientPort) {
        this.clientPort = clientPort;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        /**
         * Create a new server socket and bind it to a free port. I have chosen
         * one in the 49152 - 65535 range, which are allocated for internal applications
         */
        try (DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(50000)) {
            // The server will generate 3 messages and send them to the client
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                String message = "Message number " + i;
                DatagramPacket datagramPacket = new DatagramPacket(
                        message.getBytes(),
                        message.length(),
                        InetAddress.getLocalHost(),
                        clientPort
                );
                serverSocket.send(datagramPacket);
            }
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It might be a line endings problem. Try to replace all string output with `replace("\n", "_blaat_\n")` prior to passing them to `System.out`.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect a Charset (encoding) problem.

Try passing a Charset name to both String.getBytes() in the server app, and the String constructor in the client app, e.g.

```
   byte[] bytes = message.getBytes("UTF-8");
    DatagramPacket datagramPacket = new DatagramPacket(
                            bytes,
                            bytes.length,
                            InetAddress.getLocalHost(),
                            clientPort
                    );
```

and

```
String receivedMessage = new String(datagramPacket.getData(), "UTF-8");
```

- Edit - also make sure that you're using the correct length for the outbound datagram, recognizing that the length of the string in chars is not necessarily the length of the byte array (in bytes). Updated the example code.